# Make Custom Text Fields

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm Beginner in IOS development, and now I'm creating a form for user registration. However the text field that is default in xcode doesn't look pretty please anyone can tell me how to make a custom text field such us in Facebook application or Lynda application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you want to change in `Storyboard` or `xib` using

**Attribute**

[image]

In `UITextField` Attribute property has `BorderStyle` set as  `None` , you can customize the width and height , whatever you need you can change

the `UITextBorderStyle` Property type as

```
UITextBorderStyleNone,
UITextBorderStyleLine,
UITextBorderStyleBezel,
UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect
```

If set to `UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect`, custom background images are ignored.else three things you can customize.

additional [apple Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/)

*programmatically*

**Objective-C**

```
UITextField *txtEmailfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 40)];
txtEmailfield.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
txtEmailfield.placeholder = @"Email(Required)";
txtEmailfield.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
txtEmailfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
txtEmailfield.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
txtEmailfield.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
txtEmailfield.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
txtEmailfield.delegate = self;
txtEmailfield.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleNone;
[self.view addSubview:txtEmailfield];
```

**Swift**

```
var txtEmailfield = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(10.0, 20.0, 300.0,40.0))
txtEmailfield.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
txtEmailfield.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
txtEmailfield.font=UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
txtEmailfield.placeholder="Email(Required)"
txtEmailfield.autocorrectionType=UITextAutocorrectionType.No
txtEmailfield.keyboardType=UIKeyboardType.Default
txtEmailfield.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyType.Done
txtEmailfield.delegate = self
txtEmailfield.clearButtonMode=UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing
txtEmailfield.contentVerticalAlignment=UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center
self.view.addSubview(txtEmailfield)
```

Comment: Like the photo that you have posted can you post the code please so i can have a clear idea

Comment: if u want to create the textfield in progmatically in above image like

Answer (score 0):

There are various properties in UITextField class which you can use to customize the text field. e.g borderStyle property to customize the border whether you want rounded rect or line etc..
Go through the below link : 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/

Answer (score 0):

Create a subclass that inherits from UITextfield, then rewrite some methods or add some custom views in layoutsubviews. And you can check this page from apple to see what UITextfield have.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the UI of the textField, you can do this in your storyboard or nib:

[image]

Notice the Border Style, the default one is RoundRect (the 4th one). but if you want to customize the UI, choose the 1st one (BorderStyle: None)

Now you can put background image or change it's color and text as you what you wanted.